# how to create gemsets in windows using pik?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pik

I am using windows machine and want to install pik (similar to RVM) for managing different versions of ruby and rails. However as far as I know pik currently do not have facility to create gemsets as we do with RVM.
In such a case how do I create gemsets in windows for bundling my gems. And if pik supports such a feature then please some guide me through it.

Comment: Please refer to question mentioned on the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794915/ruby-on-rails-pik-gemset-like-rvm-gemset/15795225#

Answer (score 1):

There is some workaround to deal with a gemsets using pik. This may help you:

https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/16#issuecomment-3515658