# ruby on rails PIK gemset like RVM gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, pik

I've worked with RVM where I can get gemset's and stuff, but there's no way of getting it with PIK? any idea? I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find one. Hopefully someone has any clue on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As refer to below link we can use pik on windows instead of rvm as a workaround:

```
https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/16#issuecomment-3515658
```

In case anyone is interested, I've just tried a simplistic work-around. So far, so good...

```
cd %HOMEPATH%\.pik\rubies
xcopy /s Ruby-193-p0 Ruby-193-p0@<gemset-name>
```

Now edit %HOMEPATH%.pik\config.yml, cloning the entry you copied from and adding the "@" where appropriate:

```
"193: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]": 
  :path: !ruby/object:Pathname 
    path: C:/Users/Nathan/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p0/bin
"193@<gemset-name>: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]": 
   :path: !ruby/object:Pathname 
    path: C:/Users/Nathan/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p0@<gemset-name>/bin
```

Then at the command line...

```
pik list

* 193: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
  193@<gemset-name>: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

pik switch 193@<gemset-name>

pik list
  193: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
* 193@<gemset-name>: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
```

That's it! Of course, YMMV. Post back if you improve this on this hack!

This may useful for you.